# Mongo query to find bookings within a range of date

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

There are some old booking data such as following

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec3df592d2c6146204ca8fd"),
    "space" : "5ea974b82d2c614721d69b08",
    "eventTypeId" : "5e8e0fe22d2c6104bdf55699",
    "bookingStartDate" : ISODate("2020-07-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "bookingEndDate" : ISODate("2020-07-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec3df592d2c6146204ca8fd"),
    "space" : "5ea974b82d2c614721d69b08",
    "eventTypeId" : "5e8e0fe22d2c6104bdf55699",
    "bookingStartDate" : ISODate("2020-07-15T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "bookingEndDate" : ISODate("2020-07-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec3df592d2c6146204ca8fd"),
    "space" : "5ea974b82d2c614721d69b08",
    "eventTypeId" : "5e8e0fe22d2c6104bdf55699",
    "bookingStartDate" : ISODate("2020-07-20T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "bookingEndDate" : ISODate("2020-07-26T00:00:00.000Z"),
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec3df592d2c6146204ca8fd"),
    "space" : "5ea974b82d2c614721d69b08",
    "eventTypeId" : "5e8e0fe22d2c6104bdf55699",
    "bookingStartDate" : ISODate("2020-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "bookingEndDate" : ISODate("2020-08-05T00:00:00.000Z"),
}
```

Now the user need to find whether there are old bookings for the new booking date range such as 2020-07-08 (newBookingStartDate) to 2020-07-20 (newBookingEndDate) by passing space,eventTypeId,newBookingStartDate and newBookingEndDate

**I need Mongo query or spring boot Mongo query for this scenario the query should return first three documents of the collection**

Comment: Convert dates to UTC timestamps then use $lte/$gte.

Comment: Is there any other way to find using ISO Date or is it compulsory to convert to UTC :)

Comment: MongoDB does not store timezones, so all of the times must be provided in UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the query which i tried based on provided collection records.

```
var startDate = ISODate("2020-07-08T00:00:00.000Z");
var endDate = ISODate("2020-07-20T00:00:00.000Z");
db.getCollection('collectionName').find({
    "$and":[
        {"bookingStartDate":{"$gte":startDate}},
        {"bookingStartDate":{"$lte":endDate}}
    ]
});
```

I got the result like this

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec3df592d2c6146204ca8fd"),
    "space" : "5ea974b82d2c614721d69b08",
    "eventTypeId" : "5e8e0fe22d2c6104bdf55699",
    "bookingStartDate" : ISODate("2020-07-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "bookingEndDate" : ISODate("2020-07-12T00:00:00.000Z")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec3df592d2c6146204ca8fc"),
    "space" : "5ea974b82d2c614721d69b08",
    "eventTypeId" : "5e8e0fe22d2c6104bdf55699",
    "bookingStartDate" : ISODate("2020-07-15T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "bookingEndDate" : ISODate("2020-07-17T00:00:00.000Z")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec3df592d2c6146204ca8f8"),
    "space" : "5ea974b82d2c614721d69b08",
    "eventTypeId" : "5e8e0fe22d2c6104bdf55699",
    "bookingStartDate" : ISODate("2020-07-20T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "bookingEndDate" : ISODate("2020-07-26T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```